# Repeater Control paging error

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to create a pager in a repeater control. The content is being pulled from the database and is displaying but when I click on the previous and next buttons they don't page, that is, I stay on the same content. Would anyone be able to see the error from the code below? No errors or showing so I think it is something minor but I have been banging my head against a wall trying to find it

Markup:

```
<asp:Repeater ID="ArtRepeater" runat="server">
<HeaderTemplate>
    <h2>Items in Selected Category:</h2>
</HeaderTemplate>  
<ItemTemplate>
    <li>
        <asp:HyperLink runat="server" ID="HyperLink"
            NavigateUrl='<%# Eval("MovieID", "Default2.aspx?ArtID={0}")%>'>
            <%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "MovieTitle")%>
        </asp:HyperLink>
    </li>
</ItemTemplate>
```

Code Behind:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    doPaging()
End Sub

Function getTheData() As DataTable
        Dim DS As New DataSet()
        Dim strConnect As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " & _
        Server.MapPath("/App_Data/MovieBoard.accdb"))
        Dim objOleDBAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT MovieID, MovieTitle FROM Movies", strConnect)
        objOleDBAdapter.Fill(DS, "Movies")

        Return DS.Tables("Movies").Copy
    End Function

    Sub doPaging()
        pagedData.DataSource = getTheData().DefaultView
        pagedData.AllowPaging = True
        pagedData.PageSize = 1

        Try
            pagedData.CurrentPageIndex = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString("Page")).ToString()
        Catch ex As Exception
            pagedData.CurrentPageIndex = 0
        End Try

        btnPrev.Visible = (pagedData.IsFirstPage)
        btnNext.Visible = (Not pagedData.IsLastPage)

        pageNumber.Text = (pagedData.CurrentPageIndex + 1) & " of " & pagedData.PageCount

        ArtRepeater.DataSource = pagedData
        ArtRepeater.DataBind()
    End Sub
```

Comment: When are you calling these functions? Postback, every page load, etc.?

Comment: Every page load. I have them calling so the content is showing just not paging

Comment: I don't see doPaging() attached to the Repeater

Comment: What is the type of your pagedData object? Will it filter the datasource itself? Most .Net data source controls don't by default. Also, it looks like the OLEDB command you're sending will return all the result to the control every time. So even if pagedData is filtering by page (which it may not), it could easily become a very bad performing page if the data set gets large enough.

Comment: It is of PagedDataSource. It won't get to large so that wont be an issue

Answer (score 0):

After banging my head against a wall I found a solution. I forgot to connect the buttons to the repeater control. Here's a solution:

```
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Partial Class Default2
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Dim pagedData As New PagedDataSource

Protected Sub Page_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    doPaging()
End Sub

Function getTheData() As DataTable
    Dim DS As New DataSet()
    Dim strConnect As New OleDbConnection("Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source = " & _
    Server.MapPath("/App_Data/MovieBoard.accdb"))
    Dim objOleDBAdapter As New OleDbDataAdapter("SELECT MovieID, MovieTitle FROM Movies", strConnect)
    objOleDBAdapter.Fill(DS, "Movies")

    Return DS.Tables("Movies").Copy
End Function

Sub doPaging()
    pagedData.DataSource = getTheData().DefaultView
    pagedData.AllowPaging = True
    pagedData.PageSize = 1

    Try
        pagedData.CurrentPageIndex = Int32.Parse(Request.QueryString("Page")).ToString()
    Catch ex As Exception
        pagedData.CurrentPageIndex = 0
    End Try

    btnPrev.Visible = (Not pagedData.IsFirstPage)
    btnNext.Visible = (Not pagedData.IsLastPage)

    If Not pagedData.IsFirstPage Then
        btnPrev.PostBackUrl = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath + _
                                       "?Page=" + CStr(pagedData.CurrentPageIndex - 1)
    End If

    If Not pagedData.IsLastPage Then
        btnNext.PostBackUrl = Request.CurrentExecutionFilePath + _
                                       "?Page=" + CStr(pagedData.CurrentPageIndex + 1)
    End If

    pageNumber.Text = (pagedData.CurrentPageIndex + 1) & " of " & pagedData.PageCount

    ArtRepeater.DataSource = pagedData
    ArtRepeater.DataBind()
```